# Disabling the top bar in Ubuntu - not looking for gnome extenstions

Tags: 20.04, compiz, gnome-shell, gui, ccsm

in ubuntu 14 I used ccsm to switch profiles, one of this profiles disabled all gui except for the Desktop.
However, in Ubuntu 20 ccsm is not working anymore (new profile creation fails).

I am looking for an option to disable the top bar, however gnome extensions only hides the top bar when a window is open. I would need the disabling to be permanet, at least until it is enabled again via terminal.

Comment: is it Ubuntu 20.04 Default one or have you done any customizatinos?

Comment: can you try this command `gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval string:'Main.panel.actor.hide();'` later we can go for "not looking for gnome extensions" part from your Question.

Comment: yes, I have the default installation. Thank you so much, that's exactly what I was looking for. Every other solution I found until now just linked to [link](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/740/hide-top-panel/) which did not solve my problem, but this works just fine, and .show() makes the top bar visible again.

Comment: Again, thank you very much. you saved me quite some headaches.

Comment: Hi... But when you refresh gnome-shell it rests the command and shows topbar. Try to refresh gnome-shell with key press of Alt+f2 then type `restart` n hit enter

Comment: I know it is kind of hacky, but my idea was to create a start script to disable the top bar. Then whenever the pc is restarted, the top bar is disabled. Would you think this is an appropriate solution?

Comment: When you Logout reboot you can manage this with startup application pfeferences but when shell is restarted you have to manually run the command so here starts the extension part.. since you mentioned dont want extensions there is no other way. The same command can be converted to gnome-shell extension to have persistence. See my second comment and respond.